# aws s3 buckets are not showing on web console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the aws cli setup on my mac and when I list my buckets on the terminal with the command `aws s3 ls` I get to see four buckets which I can't see listed in the web console.

I have created an IAM user and when I use the same cli command above with the `--profile [username]` flag, I see the same bucket that I see in the web console shows up.

My question is: where do I find the four buckets that I see via cli? Why can't I see them on the web console?

I am signed in as both root user and IAM user in separate browsers and I still don't see the buckets listed via cli on the web console

One of these mysterious buckets is listed in `ap-northeast-1` region. As a root user I can still see the same region being used in the url params as `region=ap-northeast-1`. I still don't see the four buckets. I see only one that belongs to the IAM user

Comment: What is the difference between the default profile you are using with the CLI tool, and the profile you are using when you specify `--profile` that results in the 4 buckets not being listed? You need to examine those two IAM users/profiles to see what the difference is.

Comment: One is a root user and the other is an IAM user. In the web console I can only see the bucket belonging to the IAM user. Whereas the 4 buckets listed on the cli are not VISIBLE at all

Comment: What happens when you login to the web console as the root user?

Comment: I see only the one bucket belonging to the IAM user instead of the four buckets listed via cli

Comment: Is it possible that those 4 buckets were shared to your account from another AWS account? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html

Comment: hmm - I don't think so. But I would like to double check. What command can I use to check which account the aws bucket belongs to?

Comment: Try running `aws s3api list-buckets` using your default profile which lists all the buckets, and see what Owner information is displayed.

Comment: shit you are right - these seem to be created via some other amazon account. So how do I now make sure that my aws cli tool uses the default config stored in my credentials file inside my .aws folder?

Comment: The CLI tool uses the default credentials in the .aws folder by default. That's why it's called the **default** credentials. It will always use those credentials unless you explicitly specify a `--profile` option. Alternatively, look at that link I posted regarding sharing S3 buckets and configure your account so your other IAM profiles can see the buckets.

Comment: Where is the link @MarkB?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The four buckets in question were shared to your AWS account from another AWS account. They are visible in API calls by your root AWS user, but not your other IAM users. To make them show up in API calls from your other IAM users you need to follow [this guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html), in particular step 2.3 of that guide.