# Root user cannot see all S3 buckets in AWS web console

Tags: amazon-s3

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42207410/aws-s3-buckets-are-not-showing-on-web-console) question in that a particular S3 bucket I created is not visible in the web console.

Also, if I try to create a bucket of the same name..

> Bucket name already exists

For clarity, I am the root user, and the missing bucket was not shared from a different user/account as was the case with the similar question - it was created by me.

Also note, this doesn't have anything to do with region, as it's set to 'Global', and says

> S3 does not require region selection.

This seems so basic but I can't work out why the bucket is not visible

Also note, I ran `aws s3api list-buckets` and the missing bucket does not appear there either

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out [S3 bucket names have to be globally unique](https://serverfault.com/questions/899704/aws-s3-bucket-name-already-exists) which explains the "Bucket name already exists" message. Someone else had created a bucket of the same name on their account, hence why I couldn't create a bucket of that name.

The solution is simply to choose a different (globally unique) bucket name.